# Rails create new table with columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

How would I be able to create a new table with columns as the same time and set `count` to be default = 0?

I tried in terminal 
`rails g migration User_tables date:datetime user_id:integer count:integer`

it made the table without the columns though

Comment: This seems utterly missguided. What you really want to do is `rails g model user` which will create a migration with `id`, and `created_at`, `updated_at` columns as well as generating the model class. I don't get why you even want a count column as that will be per row. If you want a count of the users you do it by selecting an aggregate with `User.count`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define `default` through command line.

both `null` and `default` are not supported in command line in rails.

[Rails Doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers)

Also the migration should be like below --

```
rails g migration CreateUsers date:datetime user_id:integer count:integer
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer to my question

`rails g migration CreateUser_Tables date:datetime user_id:integer count:integer`

that made the table with the columns all in one go!